# AWS codedeploy packages installed not available in after install hook

Tags: yarnpkg, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I'm deploying a node application in aws using aws codepipeline.

appspec.yaml

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ubuntu/my-app
    overwrite: true
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/before_install.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: ubuntu
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/after_install.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: ubuntu
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/application_start.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: ubuntu
```

before_install.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get update
curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.0/install.sh -o install_nvm.sh
bash install_nvm.sh
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
nvm install --lts
npm install --location=global yarn
yarn global add pm2
```

So node, npm, yarn and pm2 is installed. Since yarn is used to intall pm2 if this runs then yarn should be successfully installed.

after_install.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/ubuntu/my-app
yarn install
yarn run build
```

After running I get following error

after_install.sh: line 7: yarn: command not found
after_install.sh: line 8: yarn: command not found

When look at build error it seems like yarn only not available in after_installation hook.

```
2022-06-20 18:21:49 [stdout]Installing latest LTS version.
2022-06-20 18:21:49 [stderr]v16.15.1 is already installed.
2022-06-20 18:21:50 [stdout]Now using node v16.15.1 (npm v8.11.0)
2022-06-20 18:21:51 [stdout]
2022-06-20 18:21:51 [stdout]changed 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 489ms
2022-06-20 18:21:51 [stdout]
2022-06-20 18:21:51 [stdout]found 0 vulnerabilities
2022-06-20 18:21:51 [stdout]yarn global v1.22.19
2022-06-20 18:21:51 [stdout][1/4] Resolving packages...
2022-06-20 18:21:51 [stdout][2/4] Fetching packages...
2022-06-20 18:21:51 [stdout][3/4] Linking dependencies...
2022-06-20 18:21:52 [stdout][4/4] Building fresh packages...
2022-06-20 18:21:52 [stdout]success Installed "pm2@5.2.0" with binaries:
2022-06-20 18:21:52 [stdout]      - pm2
2022-06-20 18:21:52 [stdout]      - pm2-dev
2022-06-20 18:21:52 [stdout]      - pm2-docker
2022-06-20 18:21:52 [stdout]      - pm2-runtime
2022-06-20 18:21:52 [stdout]Done in 1.27s.
2022-06-20 18:21:54 LifecycleEvent - AfterInstall
2022-06-20 18:21:54 Script - scripts/after_install.sh
2022-06-20 18:21:54 [stderr]/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/faee375f-f793-4b89-b57e-78c445c6c02b/d-WCHP7OWQH/deployment-archive/scripts/after_install.sh: line 7: yarn: command not found
2022-06-20 18:21:54 [stderr]/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/faee375f-f793-4b89-b57e-78c445c6c02b/d-WCHP7OWQH/deployment-archive/scripts/after_install.sh: line 8: yarn: command not found
```